# XAML tag list reference

Tags: xaml

As the question suggests I'm simply looking for a XAML tag list reference. I've banged the obvious queries in Google/SO but not found what I am looking for yet. Any useful links welcome.

Comment: Do you mean a WPF XAML list? XAML itself is somewhat technology neutral.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't such a thing as a xaml tag list.

XAML is just a declarative way to instantiate .Net classes. Class names are elements in XAML and properties on the class are attributes or attribute elements using dot notation.

Tags in XAML only mirror the types in one or more assemblies that are bound to a particular XAML namespace.

There are however a specific set of elements that are specific to XAML in itself and are not related to any particular .Net assembly, those are usually in the x: namespace, more info here: [XAML Namespace (x:)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

There's a [WPF Binding Cheatsheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2009/02/02/wpf-xaml-data-binding-cheat-sheet.aspx) and another [XAML for WPF Cheatsheet](http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/02/03/xaml-for-wpf-cheatsheet/) which might help, but really the "tags" in XAML are just the properties of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as **the** XAML tag list since XAML is an open system.

There are, however, standard vocabularies. [Rob Relyea's Blog](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea) is a good place to keep track of the standardization around these vocabluaries. For example, [this](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2008/10/14/ms-slxv-silverlight-xaml-vocabulary-2008-specification-v0-9-published.aspx) is an entry for the Silverlight XAML vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

With WPF the XAML elements map to the classes like [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx). MSDN seems to give XAML examples for many of the controls.

Answer (score 1):

There are XAML-specific conventions about representing things like complex properties and bindings. However, there is no definitive list of XAML tags. XAML tags are actually mapped to WPF objects. For example, `<Button>` is just a XAML representation of the `System.Windows.Controls.Button` class and the attributes allowed on the `<Button>` tag are the public properties of the `Button` class.

Answer (score -1):

There should be several WPF cheatsheets available soon on http://www.devsheets.com (since around September 2011) ... You can download it there, and also buy printed versions with more detailed information on them (not all content fits in publicly available pdf, because pdf would not be readable if printed on paper without high quality print ... that is why we also decided to sell high quality laminated cheatsheet prints in addition to their free versions)